# Flutter and firebase zsh:command not found: flutterfire

Tags: flutter, firebase, zsh, firebase-tools

I got zsh:command not found: flutterfire, so I did some steps to solve it.

1. firebase login
2. npm install -g firebase-tools
3. dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
4. vim ~/.zshrc (add export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin")

[image]

After these, I run `flutterfire configure --project=******` but I got same error.

What's the problem?

I got zsh:command not found: flutterfire, so I did some steps to solve it.

1. firebase login
2. npm install -g firebase-tools
3. dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
4. vim ~/.zshrc (add export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin")

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: I will point out that `firebase login` can't come before `npm install -f firebase-tools` in your set of ordered instructions because the latter is the thing that installs the `firebase` cli.

Comment: Your shell has no paranormal capabilities: It does not know that you have changed things in your .zshrc. If you want these changes to apply, create a new interactive shell.